# What is this succulent with spined leaves with a triangular cross-section?

Tags: identification, houseplants, container-gardening, succulents, aloe

A few weeks ago I got this plant from someone:

[image]

Sadly it looks like it is dying. What kind of plant is this? I have been watering it twice a week, keeping the soil moist. What did I do wrong and how can I save it?

Comment: This is a succulent. You are over watering it.  High, high light and water every few weeks

Comment: Does the pot have any drainage holes? If not, repot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This plant is an aloe. It's a desert dwelling succulent. In warm weather they can handle being watered once a month, sometimes more often in HOT weather. Indoors they can often go several months without water before they complain. If they're watered frequently they start to suffer from drowning and root rot very quickly. The lower leaves of your plant appear yellow, but still very plump, this is a typical succulent response to over-watering.

To save it: stop over-watering. Most of the leaves still look fairly healthy, just give it a nice warm sunny window and it should recover.

Comment: Also: repotting to drier soil might help if the soil is not drying out fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely repot in a clay pot with drainage holes.  Use Cactus soil.  Put in a sunny window without its leaves touching the window pane!  They can get scorched leaves in direct sunlight or just by touching the window.  I water mine once a month, and just a dampening, not so its soaked.  Hope that helps.